# How should I design generic container components with ractive?

Tags: ractivejs

I want to create an accordian ui with ractive. I could do this with a basic template with static content, but I don't understand how to turn the template into a re-usable generic component.

It may be easier if I explain with code. Basically, I want to be able to write code *something* like this:

```
<my-accordian>
     <my-accordian-section header="section one">
         <my-other-component-a foo="apple" one="1">
         <my-other-component-b foo="banana" two="2">
     </my-accordian-section>
     <my-accordian-section>
         <my-other-component-c foo="apple" one="1">
         <my-other-component-d foo="banana" two="2">
     </my-accordian-section>
</my-accordian>
```

What's the best way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [yields](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/components#yield). All you have to do is make those "wrapper components" and assign `{{ yield }}` to where you want the inner html to appear.

**my-accordian.html**

```
<div class="accordion">
  {{yield}} <!-- anything between <my-accordian></my-accordian> --> goes here
</div>
```

**my-accordian-section.html**

```
<div class="accordion-section">
  <div class="accordion-header">
    <h3>{{ header }}</h3> <!-- the header property you passed in goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    {{ yield }} <!-- anything between <my-accordian-section></my-accordian-section> --> goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do the same thing with `{{> content }}` but the difference lies in where the inner html gets it's data. Yields would be the better option here.

Comment: Also see [named yields](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/components#yield) if you want to provide separate named blocks of "passed-in" template